# Using Global Variables in Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having issues with trying to use global variables in a multiprocessing pool. I know there is quite a lot of content on this already, but I am struggling to implement the answers to my case.

I have a function that I want to use with pool.map. I want the input of this function to be a few global variables and also one other parameter that changes process-to-process. That is I want something that looks like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

   A = Global Variable Array
   B = Global Variable Array
   C = Actual Input Array For the Multiprocessing

   pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   Res= pool.map(Function,Input = A,B,C)
```

In the above case only C varies from process-to-process. Currently my code only works if I import the global arrays from an external files within each process, which seems very wasteful.

Comment: "I want something that looks like" What stopy you from writing something that looks like this? What have you tried so far? Did you get an error? What do you intend ``Input = A, B, C`` to mean? ``Pool.map`` does not take a parameter ``Input``, and ``Input = A, B, C`` passes only ``A`` to ``Input``.

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing` provides a couple of ways to share state between processes. Access to these objects may be synchronized by `lock` arg.

> If `lock` is True (the default) then a new recursive lock object is created to synchronize access to the value. If `lock` is a Lock or RLock object then that will be used to synchronize access to the value. If `lock` is False then access to the returned object will not be automatically protected by a lock, so it will not necessarily be “process-safe”.

Example from the official documentation:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```